# python-docx modify docx file normal text type to header

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I have a docx file of the following format:

```
-------------
header 1
-------------
Text
Text

-------------
header 2
-------------
Text2
text2


-------------
header 3
-------------
Text3
text3


-------------
header 4
-------------
Text4
text4

...
```

I would like to use the docx / python-docx library to modify the docx file so that **every** (plain text) **header + number is converted to Word "Header" format, so that I can create a table of contents of all the headers.** The file contains around 1000 headers so it is very big.

Is this possible with the docx library?

Comment: Have you tried `paragraph.style = "Header 1"`?

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured it out in a bit different way: I rolled back to my attempt in **creating** the .docx file (including its headers) from scratch, because I couldn't find a way to modify the existing file (or at least, its headers).

Here is how I created the .docx file from a number of .txt files which have a heading at the beginning of every file:

```
# Find all the txt files in the dataset folder
inputs = []
for file in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\your_user_name\\your_folder'):
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        inputs.append(os.path.join("C:\\Users\\your_user_name\\your_folder", file))


# Concatenate all .txt files in a file called my_written_file.docx and add a paragraph for every .txt file content
mydoc = Document()

mydoc.add_heading("MAIN_HEADING_NAME", 0)
mydoc.add_paragraph("\n")

for fname in inputs:
    with open(fname, encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore') as infile:
        mydoc.add_heading(str(fname[65:]), 1) # sub-heading picked from the beginning of the .txt file
        mydoc.add_paragraph("\n")
        mydoc.add_paragraph(infile.read())
        mydoc.add_paragraph("\n")
mydoc.add_paragraph("\n\n\n----------END OF FILE----------")
mydoc.save("C:\\Users\\your_user_name\\your_folder\\my_written_file.docx")
```